# Dynamic linking with Firebase

Tags: firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

I am trying to set up firebase dynamic links for my app/website `www.example.com` but I am doing something wrong. Here's what I've done

1. Went to dynamic links in Firebase console to create a new dynamic link for the domain `example.com`
2. Got this error `www.example.com is not connected properly - There was a problem with your DNS configuration, check this configuration in Firebase Hosting. Note: it could take up to 24 hours for your DNS configuration to reflect recent changes.`
3. I went to hosting to connect the domain, I added the necessary `A` and `TXT` files to my DNS provider (Website is not hosted on firebase)

After this was completed I tested the dynamic links and here is what I found

1. The links were working for the app - If I clicked a link to `www.example.com` it would just take me to the associated app, which is what I wanted
2. BUT, when trying to go to the website `www.example.com` I am presented with `Invalid Dynamic Link - Requested URL must be a parsable and complete DynamicLink`

[image: Response when trying to use the website]

Why is it that Dynamic Links were working, but the website was not? How can I fix Dynamic links so that they work, as well as the website?